# how to access one managedbean from another in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have two managedbean class(`UserBean.java` & `HelloBean.java`) and one `index.xhthl` class. In `HelloBean.java` class, I have used `@ManagedProperty` anotation for accessing the property of `UserBean.java` and  I have a method within `HelloBean.java` class.

here, my classes:

**UserBean.java**

```
package com.bean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="ubean", eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }   
}
```

**HelloBean.java**

```
package com.bean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="hellobean", eager=true)
@RequestScoped
public class HelloBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{ubean}")
    private UserBean mbean;
    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        if(mbean!=null){
            username=mbean.getUsername();
        }
        return username;
    }

    public void setMbean(UserBean mbean) {
        this.mbean = mbean;
    }

    public UserBean getMbean() {
        return mbean;
    }

    public void showMsg(){  
        System.out.println("UserName :"+username);
    }
}
```

And, **index.xhtml**

```
<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{ubean.username}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{hellobean.showMsg}"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

I want to invoke the `showMsg()` method from `index.xhtml` class. The method is fired by clicking `commandButton`, but it always returns `null` instead of `inputText` value. What's the problem in my codes. Someone, helps...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think the scope of both managed beans must be the same.

Comment: how is your UserBean populated? who give it userName?

Comment: Isn't it `System.out.println("UserName :"+getUsername());` instead of `System.out.println("UserName :"+username);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `username` is the property of `UserBean.java` class. As a result, you must have to call the `username` variable through a object of the parent(`UserBean.java`) class.So, try it, `mbean.getUsername()` instead of only `username`.